# Syntax error when trying to input errors for a set of data

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a graph using Jupyter Notebooks but when I input errors for a data set "syntax error" appears referring to the word error, any ideas on the problem?

```
 measured_time2 = q.MeasurementArray(
data = [0,0.2,1.0,2.2,4.0,6.2,9.0,12.2,16.0,20.2,25]
error = [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1])

File "<ipython-input-36-96c22be70112>", line 8
error = [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1])
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Function arguments are separated by commas.

Comment: Thanks, but i believe each arg is separated by a comma, what would you recommend to change in order to make that data set correct?

Comment: I would recommend putting a comma between the function arguments.

Comment: which ones? sorry I'm very new to this, only use it every once in a while for phsyics labs

Comment: The first one and the second one.